# Keychain access in iOS and provisioning profiles

Tags: ios, security, keychain, provisioning-profile

I started to read the `Keychain Services Programming Guide` and in the `Keychain Services Concepts` there is a note:

> On iPhone, Keychain rights depend on the provisioning profile used to sign your application. Be sure to consistently use the same provisioning profile across different versions of your application.

I don't understand this note... what if for example I need a build for adHoc deployment and I need to later edit the provisioning profile to add more devices? Or if I sometimes build the app for adHoc deployment with its appropriate adHoc provisioning profile, and another times I build it to use TestFlight with its provisioning profile for the App Store?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that's true, I regenerate my provisioning profiles every year and haven't lost keychain access.

What exactly constitutes keychain "identity" is hard to pin down.

[QA1726](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1726/_index.html) seems to imply that your keychain access is based on BundleID Prefix/Team ID *plus* bundle ID. Although bundle IDs are allowed to differ if you use the `keychain-access-groups` entitlement.

I would also hazard that provisioning profile *type* now comes into play.

e.g. once upon a time I could read the keychain of the AppStore version of our app from an Ad Hoc version of the app, but not a dev version, but that seemed to stop working around iOS 7.

I hope somebody can contribute some slightly less conjectural information.

Answer (score 0):

it says about the every year the profile expired and updated with new one.this should be same. see [here](http://devquestion.tk/13313715/does-renewing-a-provisioning-profile-affect-keychain-access-when-i-submit-an-app.html), more [here](https://github.com/MugunthKumar/MKStoreKit/issues/164)